# Validation for array

Tags: php, arrays, validation, multidimensional-array

How can I validate the multidimensional array.My array is like

```
Array
(
    [level] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [subject] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 9
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

I want to check the keys for *[level]* is in *[subject]*. Please help me. How it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (count(array_intersect_key($array['level'], $array['subject'])) !=
    count($array['level'])) {
    echo 'level and subject have different keys';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood:

```
array_diff_key($myArray['level']), $myArray['subject']);
```

sample: http://codepad.org/i00KNhDJ

Order is important:

```
array_diff_key($myArray['level']), $myArray['subject']) !== array_diff_key($myArray['subject']), $myArray['level']);
```

Comment: Use `array_diff_key`?